# Change theme color in Android Studio of Resouce identifier

Tags: android-studio, themes

does anyone know where I can change the theme color of the identifier of a Resource in Android studio?

Currently I have a black theme, but the purple color makes it unreadable. I have tried other dark themes but it always stays purple. I searched for it in settings but I was unable to find it.

[example image of how it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mWcZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to File->settings->Editor->Color&Fonts where you can make a copy of the default theme and change colors of everything.

Comment: The problem is, I can't seem to find that purple color. You know what tab it is under at Color&Fonts?

Answer (score 0):

File->settings->Editor->Color&Fonts
If you want more theme you can google it download it and then import it in the Android studio